# Django how to use variable into src tag

Tags: python, django

i am making a website.I have a table in my db which is named Adds.Every record has one field and the field contains an url to a image.Everytime the add box has to contain different add.I made the script who gets random add from the db.I have to display it in my html.How can i do this?Something like this

```
<img src = "{{myvariable}}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. What is your question?

Comment: i am not at home and i forgot the most importanat part.I wanted to ask if this will work?

Answer (score 0):

If u upload image

Then use:

`<img src="/media/{{variable}}" alt="{{image-title}}"/>`

Please check the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/